# eclipse luna code template for java commands to use auto suggestion

Tags: java, eclipse

can some one help me with eclipse code template for luna for commonly used java commands...ctrl + space does not yield anything, meaning cannot locate the file with abbreviations...so what/where is the file located or from where do I need to import it ?

thanks.

Comment: not clear...is your auto code completion not working ?

Comment: auto code completion works in limited fashion;am new to code templates in eclipse;where are the code template files located?for eg., typing while or for loop and ctrl+space (ctrl + space is default I guess)does not get me the loop structure...or typing svm and ctrl+space will not give me static void main method... thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can check the code templates for java by going to

WIndows->Preferences->java->Editor->Templates ...

and check whether the template for "for" loop is missing or not.
The default eclipse installation must not disturb the default templates.
You can try to restore defaults if there have been some changes
Hope this helps

Regards,

Saurav